# How to get a remote desktop server (RDP) to automatically SSH back to a connecting client?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, automation

I am trying to automate the process of connecting to a Windows machine via RDP and then initiating an ssh tunnel back to the client machine.

The way I currently manually handle this:

1. I log into the RDP server and run the following command to aid in helping me find the right IP address:

   `netstat -a | find "3389" | find "ESTABLISHED"`

   This spits out a line that contains the connection details for my computer's rdp connection. This IP is the IP that the server will be able to route through back to my computer.
2. I manually open PuTTY and open an existing session that's properly configured with username and key, change the IP appropriately, and click connect.

At this point on my client machine I can now access some resources via the ssh port forwarding.

What I would like to do is figure out some way to automate this. The Microsoft remote desktop client has the ability to launch an program upon connection. What I don't know is what program or combination of programs to run.

Answer (score 0):

Plink is a command line connection helper for Putty. Using Plink you can avoid the manual operations that you are performing in step 2

> I manually open PuTTY and open an existing session that's properly configured with username and key, change the IP appropriately, and click connect.

For the arguments to Plink I'd suggest further [piping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) the IP address you correctly obtained using netstat and find.

So in the end the command might look like

> netstat -a | find "3389" | find "ESTABLISHED" > | plink -ssh

Remember to establish that plink is supposed to use SSH like in the above command, or better still set the windows environment variable **PLINK_PROTOCOL** to ***ssh***.

Also ensure that the plink executable file's path is established in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: The netstat line doesn't result in just a single IP, only one line out netstat output.